# Is there anyway to speed up or replace LIKE searching query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `data` with about 500.000 records, the table have:

```
id, 
title, 
created_date, 
content...
```

columns. In those column, the `content` column contain large size text.

I've used search query:

```
SELECT count(*) from data WHERE content LIKE (%keyword%);
```

This query have execute time around 9 seconds.

I tried to use Full Text Search and using this query

```
SELECT count(*) from data 
WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST ('keyword*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

The query have much shorter execute time, just about 0.4 second but the results is not the same as query which use `LIKE` operator.

As the MySQL documentation, the full text search query above can only return records that have type like "keyword---" and ignore "---keyword" and it can not meet my search requirement.

So, i want to ask if we have any other way to replace `LIKE` operator or any way to speed up the searching with LIKE ?

Comment: why not just search in natural language mode (instead of boolean), like this example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=815e1b9f5e0cbe67160af523d4b2cd79 ?

Comment: Both natural language mode and boolean mode return the number of of results less than ```LIKE``` query

Comment: when you're querying with like you're using `%keyword%`  but when you're querying with full text using `keyword*` why? If you want both to be equal then use `*keyword*`

Comment: @VietNguyenHuy can you please show a sample of the affected data, then show the results of the LIKE query, and the results of the full text query, for comparison? Because it's unclear to me how that could happen. You could use the DBFiddle to make a demo, that would help a lot.

Comment: @VietNguyenHuy actually it occurred to me...are you trying to search for text _within_ a word? Rather than an actual word? Apart from the * in boolean mode which, as you've discovered, can only be _appended_ to a word, not _prepended_, the rest of full text search assumes you're searching for entire words, not parts of words. LIKE is more appropriate for doing that, but, since it's a more basic string search it takes longer. Perhaps you could do better as the answer below suggests and configure a different search engine. I don't have experience of those so  I can't say if they will do the job

Comment: @Kaushik the * cannot be prepended to the search term in full text search. It can only be appended to the end. Check the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Comment: @VietNguyenHuy . . . And, alas, MySQL's full text capabilities do not include a synonym list.  If you need serious search capabilities, you might want to consider a different database.

Comment: @ADyson yes, i'm trying the search all words which are the same as the keyword and words which contain keyword. And the query performance affect by the number of records in database(Around 500.000 records as i counted), so making and fiddle example can not explain the whole situation. May be i should try another search engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LOCATE()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_locate.asp):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data WHERE LOCATE("keyword", content) > 0
```

Or [INSTR()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-instr-function.php):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data WHERE INSTR(content, "keyword") > 0
```

Comment: I tested it again, the searching time is nearly the same to  ```LIKE``` query

Comment: this will query all the rows!

Comment: @VietNguyenHuy You can check the `INSTR()` as well, but `LOCATE()` should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a lot of text in your DB and need such kind of search you could do several things:

- you can configure full-text search indexes in MySQL
- you can use another full-text search DB engines like Sphinx or Elastic Search. They are much more powerful and scalable comparing to native MySQL full-text search.

Also about full-text search in MySQL. Try to use `+` instead of `*`.

- With `*` words match if they begin with the word preceding the * operator.
- A leading `+` sign indicates that a word must be present in each row that is returned.

Comment: I tried MySQL full-text search, the searched results is less than i expected.

Comment: May be '+' sign against '*'? If you use `*` word match if they begin with the word preceding the * operator. But with `+` they should simply exists.

Comment: Usharovski, As my understanding, '+' sign can only find records which contain exactly "keyword", so words which have 'keyword' within can not be searched ? And that make search results different from results of  ```LIKE``` query. Please correct me if my understanding was wrong